# How to stop masterdetail from going to detail

Tags: xcode

The Xcode MasterDetail template comes loaded with the ">" symbol on the right of each row.  If you click the row, it switches to the Detail view.  How do I block the">" symbol and how to I stop it from changing views?

Comment: why you need to block the changing the detail view when you select the row in master view?

Answer (score 0):

Go to file named "Main.storyboard" in your project. You'll see that the right two of the three view controllers are labeled Master View Controller and Detail View Controller.

Then, located the arrow in between them. This is the segue between the two view controllers. If you select it by clicking the circle in the center of it and hit the delete key on your keyboard to remove the segue, this will stop the transition from happening. You will however have to set the cells to deselect themselves after you select them.

Comment: However, I do want the + button to go to the detail view.  Also, how would I get rid of the ">" on each row?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my questions:

(1) the ">" sign is shown on each row because in the Attributes Inspector, there is an option called "Accessory" which was clicked to "Disclosure Indicator".  If you change this to "None", the ">" goes away.

(2)  The way to stop the segue when the row is clicked is to use the method `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender` and put in the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if (_addNewRecord == 1 )
        {return YES;}  // continue w/ the segue
    else
        {return NO;} // don't do the segue
}
```

I set the _addNewRecord to 1 when the "+" was clicked and to 0 elsewhere.